# Is there a way when searching for things to make the highlight more obvious?

Tags: search, firefox, browser

I'm using FireFox and sometimes the page is so cluttered when I press ctrl+f it says it found a match but I can't see where on the page it is. Is there a plugin or program I can use to make it more obvious?

Comment: why the close vote?

Comment: Indeed. Questions on browser functionality are off-topic here. Super User is the place for those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Highlight all" option it is right next to where you type in the word your are searching for. It takes each of the terms it finds and turns it a color, just like a highlighter does.